# Ant won't find classes in libs folder

Tags: java, android, ant

Since last update of ADT & build tools, I cannot build my application via the `ant release` request.

The ant output shows multiple "cannot find symbol" errors when referencing a **class file** located in a **subfolder** of `libs/`.

I tried modifying ant's build.xml as following :

```
<path id="java.compiler.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${jar.libs.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jar **/*.class" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

But it doesn't work.

Compiling via Eclipse is fine.

I am truly not an ant expert, but is there something obvious I am missing ?

**EDIT** :

- I tried updating ant and it changes nothing.
- I also tried replacing the code above by the following, without success :

  ```
  <path id="java.compiler.classpath">
       <fileset dir="${jar.libs.dir}">
              <include name="**/*.jar" />
       </fileset>
       <pathelement location="${jar.libs.dir}" />
  </path>
  ```

Any ideas ?

Comment: check your build path -> Order and Export and mark Private Libraries as exported

Comment: @TomislavNovoselec This is already the case

Answer (score 0):

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html
Try this, you might be able to find the solution due to the update.
If not that..maybe this one..
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your include is correct. I think you need to do it like this:

```
<include name="**/*.jar" />
<include name="**/*.class" />
```

Here is a way I've done it previously:

```
<fileset dir = "${lib}" includes = "**/*.jar"/>
<fileset dir = "${webLib}" includes = "**/*.jar"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I tried both versions you provided, and none of them fix the issue.